# Creating an a tag in JavaScript to add a link to a text line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have researched a few suggestions on this, but most of them append the link to the body, not a line of text. For example, I want a webpage to say something like, "Live view image not currently available, redirect to Job Status page: Link text"

the code I have is:
$('#counter').html('Live view image not currently available, redirect to Job Status page: Link text');

before I was adding the link I had $('#counter').html('Live view image not currently available') and that was working successfully.

Sorry the code I currently have is:

```
    $('#counter').html('Live view image not currently available, redirect to Job Status page: <a href="/jobs/status/?username='+username+'&token='+token+'&taskid='+taskId'">Link text</a>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a `+` after the `taskId` variable:

```
$('#counter').html('Live view image not currently available, redirect to Job Status page: <a href="/jobs/status/?username='+username+'&token='+token+'&taskid='+taskId+'">Link text</a>')
                                                                                                                                                                      ^
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my issue, even with the + it looked exactly the same inside of the element inspector with or with out it!